# How to move the UITextField up in sync with the keyboard moving up?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` embedded inside a `UIScrollView`. The textfield gets hidden by the keyboard when the keyboard shows up.

I use the following code which sets up observers for `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification` and sets the `contentInset` of the `UIScrollView` accordingly.

```swift
extension ViewController {
    func addKeyboardNotificationsObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeShown(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }
    @objc func keyboardWillBeShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard
            let kbRect = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect,
            let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber,
            let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        else { return }

        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: kbRect.height, right: 0)

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration.doubleValue,
            delay: .zero,
            options: .init(rawValue: curve.uintValue << 16),
            animations: {
                self.scrollView.contentInset = insets
                self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
            },
            completion: nil
        )
    }
    @objc func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
        scrollView.contentInset = .zero
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    }
}
```

The code works. However, the textfield gets partially hidden momentarily when the keyboard appears. The textfield appears to jump up near the end of the animation.

[image: GIF of keyboard moving up]

[image: GIF of keyboard moving up in slow motion]

Can anyone point out how to fix this so that the textfield moves up in sync with the keyboard coming up and does not appear as jumping up near the end of the animation?

Comment: You can use IQKeyboardManager https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: use tpkeyboardavoiding pod it will help